# At least one of the duplicate records has 'x'. Postgres sql EXISTS or INNER JOIN

Tags: postgresql, join, exists

I have the below postgres query that finds duplicate records in a database but I'm hoping to add in another condition so that I can say AT LEAST ONE of the duplicated records has the values of v.varfield_type_code = 's' AND v.field_content ~ 'Greendale student cards%' (from a table called sierra_view.varfield v ON p.record_id = v.record_id).

I tried an INNER JOIN and am looking into EXISTS. Does anyone have any insight? Thank you.

```
SELECT 
p.birth_date_gmt, 'p' || rm2.record_num || 'a' AS "patron",
n.last_name || ' ' || n.first_name || ' ' || n.middle_name as name,
count(*) as cnt
FROM 
sierra_view.patron_record p
JOIN sierra_view.patron_record_fullname n ON p.record_id = 
n.patron_record_id
JOIN sierra_view.record_metadata rm2 on p.record_id = rm2.id
/* JOIN sierra_view.varfield v on p.record_id =v.record_id */
WHERE p.birth_date_gmt BETWEEN '01-01-2001' AND '12-31-2017'
GROUP BY 1,2, 3
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
ORDER BY 2,1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put these conditions in the `HAVING` section:

```
JOIN sierra_view.varfield v on p.record_id = v.record_id
WHERE ...
GROUP BY ...
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND COUNT(CASE WHEN v.varfield_type_code = 's' AND v.field_content ~ 'Greendale student cards%' THEN 1 END) > 0
```

So:

- `COUNT(*) > 1` = Only include duplicate records (you already do this)
- `COUNT(CASE WHEN v.varfield_type_code = 's' AND v.field_content ~ 'Greendale student cards%' THEN 1 END) > 0` = Count the grouped records based on those two conditions; if a record matches, it gets a 1, otherwise a NULL (implicit), and NULLs are not counted. So if at least one of the grouped records matches the criteria, the whole "group" will be included in the results; if not, they won't be included.

Also worth double checking whether `~ 'Greendale student cards%'` is correct; `~` is for a regex check, while `%` is a wildcard symbol for `LIKE`, unless of course you do mean to search for a literal `%` character.

Comment: Thanks. I changed out ~ and used HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND COUNT(CASE WHEN v.varfield_type_code = 's' AND v.field_content LIKE 'Greendale student cards%') THEN 1 END) > 0. The query ran and did not break but it didn't retrieve the correct results. The results give me only Greendale student records and they are not duplicates. Hmm. However, thankyou.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to say without seeing some sample data. Can you use something like https://www.db-fiddle.com/ to create a mock dataset with small amount of fake data in order to recreate this?